# Twitter Tweet Button

Tags: javascript, button, twitter, tweets

I'm using the example of a twitter button, i'm able to tweet from my page, but when i do that, the tweet count  of my button doesn't increase, if I refresh my page several times i can see that the count is increased, how i can do to refresh(or simulate) the count of the tweet button at client side?

Here is my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="es" data-size="large">Twittear</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you have tweeted with that button on your page, the count does not increase straightaway unless you refresh?

Comment: That's right, i want that when the user makes a tweet, increase the  count  without refresh the page so the user have a visual hint about his tweet that was counted